# Text or tooltip for QGIS drag and drop form designer

Tags: qgis, forms

Is there a way, to add tool tips or a simple text next to a field widget in QGIS forms drag and drop designer?

I would like to provide more information about some fields (restrictions, expected value etc.) to the user to help him, filling in the form.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with HTML code.
Select the `HTML Widget Option`.

[image]

You can then configure each text node as a link using `<a>` and assign it a title.

[image]

The code i used (taken as an example from [here](http://sites.cognitivescience.co/knowledgebase/resources/using-google-sites/creating-mouseover-text-with-html)):

```
<a href=" " title="This is some text I want to display." style="background-color:#FFFFFF;color:#000000;text-decoration:none"> ID  </a>:
```

The `<script>` part was generated from me adding the field i wanted, and it's simply wrapped in a link tag.
Since these will be the field labels, you should turn the labels off.

[image]

This is the end result.

[image]

You can continue to style the labels with css so they would look better, but this is the basic version of what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have HTML widget visible in the Available Widgets list? Is there somewhere to turn it on? I am working on a Postgis layer, I don't know if this makes a difference?

Comment: This is probably a version issue, which QGIS version are you using? I get it as available in 3.10 with a PostGIS layer

Comment: @MartinHügi did you try upgrading QGIS?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have tried it in 3.8 now and HTML widget is there. I don't completely follow the instructions, but I have given it a go and I do get something like as shown in your end result. I just need to spend some time working out how to get it to layout as I want.. Thanks for your answer. Enjoy your bounty!

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the height of the HTML widget?