# Translating QGIS attribute table field headings into fully fledged questions for QField

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qfield

QField inherits all customization and settings of the forms done in the QGIS project. I would like to spell out the questions instead of having field headings, for example "What is the household size?" and not have "Househsize". So that in QField I have the question spelled out in full.

Answer (score 3):

You may use an alias for your field name when you configure the attribute form. (if the alias is not displayed make sure that the show label box is on)

[image]
[image]

If you want more fancy display you may use an HTML widget see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347503/text-or-tooltip-for-qgis-drag-and-drop-form-designer) for basic setting