# Editing the feature form in QGIS 3.32v

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to handle the feature form whenever I add a feature to a layer.
I have set the 'link_id' field of the layer to read-only using pyqgis. The code is mentioned below:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
formConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
formConfig.setReadOnly(0,True)
layer.setEditFormConfig(formConfig)
```

[image]
Now, the 'link_id' field says NULL. I want to let the user know that 'link_id' will be calculated automatically from the backend (custom plugin). Is there any way to set a placeholder text / hover information/ some note in the pop-up dialog saying 'link_id' is calculated from backend.
Is there any other way to handle the feature form to communicate the information?

Edit : Is there any way to add a HTML widget/ text widget to a feature form using pyqgis. The below image is what I want to achieve using pyqgis:

[image]

Comment: Not the prettiest solution but would something like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347503/text-or-tooltip-for-qgis-drag-and-drop-form-designer suffice?

Comment: Is there any other way? Is placeholder such as 'autogenerate' possible in ''integer' field like link_id. (using pyqgis)

Comment: Else, let me know how to set the html widget using pyqgis?

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to add this information.

The first is to set an alias for your field in the attribute form (this is good for short precision) in your case you could set the alias to `Link_ID (calculated automaticaly)` for exemple

[image]

The second way is to add a text widget where you could input more text and explain what will happen

[image]

[image]

As said in previous comment you may use the HTML widget rather than the text widget to output fancier formatted text if needed

Comment: How to achieve this using pyqgis?

Comment: Any idea on how to add an html widget/ text edit widget using pyqgis?

Comment: @BenStone unfortunatly not, This : https://www.qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Edit/QgsEditFormConfig.html may help...

Comment: Is there anybody who knows how to add a html widget